# How to define in java code that a field would be mantadatory in WSDL file?

Tags: java, xml, web-services

I am using Apache CXF for developing Web services .
This is some part of WSDL generated by the Apache CXF Soap Engine

```
<xs:complexContent>
<xs:extension base="tns:serviceRequest">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="xmlMessage" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="orderInputForm" type="tns:orderForm"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:extension>
</xs:complexContent>
```

Please let me know how can i make sure that a particular field is mantadatory ??

As the WSDL  is generated by Apache CXF Engine , i dont have any control on WSDL file .
So i need to make changes inside the java code itself ,  so that on to the WSDL it displays that a particular field is mantadatory

Comment: Can you annotate an element with `@XmlElement(required=true)` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using xjc or other JAXB implementation to generate your java classes you can supply additional [JAXB Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html) to handle your special cases.

If you annotate the generated code, it will be scrubbed out when the code is regenerated from the XSDL.

If you are using wsimport you can include a JAXB binding definition using the -b parameter.

Comment: I am using CXF , when i used on a Field  @XmlElement(required = true), It Application did not started Error on Server console SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Jan 12, 2012 8:34:03 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/tata-ws] startup failed due to previous errors